# Livewire wont bind the value in custom DatePicker unless I input on the text field

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-9

Why is that the wire model only updates the value if I will input in the text field?
It should be updated once I click the date.

[image]

In my form.blade.php

```
<div>
 <x-form.datepicker wireModel="user_birthdate" label="Birthdate" />
</div>
```

Here is on my component code

```
    <div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none">
        <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 2a1 1 0 00-1 1v1H4a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2h12a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2h-1V3a1 1 0 10-2 0v1H7V3a1 1 0 00-1-1zm0 5a1 1 0 000 2h8a1 1 0 100-2H6z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    </div>

    <input id="{{ $wireModel }}" class="block rounded-t-lg pl-10 px-2.5 pb-2.5 pt-5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 border-0 border-b-2 border-gray-300 appearance-none dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-blue-600 peer
    
    @error($wireModel) dark:border-red-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 border-red-600 focus:border-red-600 dark:focus-border-red-500 @enderror
    "
        datepicker datepicker-autohide type="text" 
        placeholder=" " 
        id="{{ $wireModel }}"
        name="{{ $wireModel }}"
        wire:model="{{ $wireModel }}"
    />
    <label for="{{ $wireModel }}" class="absolute text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 duration-300 transform -translate-y-4 scale-75 top-4 z-10 origin-[0] left-2.5 
        peer-focus:text-blue-600 peer-focus:dark:text-blue-500 peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-4
         
        @error($wireModel) e-75 top-4 z-10 origin-[0] left-2.5 text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 @enderror
        
    " style="left: 2.625rem;">{{ $label }}</label>
</div>
@error($wireModel) <p class="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 dark:text-red-400">{{ $message }}</p> @enderror
```

Answer (score -1):

You have given input type is to `text` replaced it with type `date`.

It will work.

Comment: https://flowbite.com/docs/plugins/datepicker/ I am using flowbite datepicker.